# using fork() in c and getting different outputs while using '\n' . what is the difference? even the pid of these are ambigous

Tags: c, unix, command, fork

i was implementing the  fork command and came across this, 
why '\n' creating so much difference.
i am getting different output if use \n.
please have a run of this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello %d\n ", getpid());
    fork();
printf("news %d \n", getpid());
return 0;
}
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello %d ", getpid());
    fork();
printf("news %d", getpid());
return 0;
}
```

output1:

```
hello 4750
news 4750 
news 4751
```

output2:

```
hello 4812 news 4812 hello 4812 news 4813
```

Comment: Please add the output you're getting to the question

Comment: Is this one of those "Spot the difference" questions? If it is, I've failed, because I can see **no** difference between the two 'halves' of your code!

Comment: You seem to have presented two copies of the same program, which  is not useful.  But what would be useful is the two *different* programs whose outputs you are comparing.  And properly formatted, please.  As presented, your code is unnecessarily difficult to read.

Comment: i have added the output

Comment: it's nothing like spot the difference. i was getting different output

Comment: Yoy've probably copied the same program two times. I assume it has to have no `\n` in the second one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it was by mistake. i corrected it